# How to hide a record in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a job website and i want that when a user posted a job it should not be shown till approval in admin panel of the website.

This is my homepage that displays jobs:

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM job ORDER BY `CreatedTime` DESC");

echo "<table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' class='table-fill'>
<tr>
<th width='300px' position='fixed' overflow='hidden'>Job Title</th> 
<th width='100px'>Company Name</th>
<th width='100px'>Location</th>
<th width='80px'>Closing Date</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td><a href='job.details.php?id=".$row['id']."' class='positiontitle-link'>" . $row['positiontitle'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['companyname'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['location'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['closingdate'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";

}

echo "</table>";
```

This is my form that job are posted via:

```
<div class="body">
        <form action="insert.php" method="post" class="ara-form">
                <header>Enter Job Details</header>

                <fieldset>                  
                    <div class="row">
                        <section class="col col-6">
                            <label class="input">
                            <i class="icon-append icon-company"></i>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Job Title" name="positiontitle">
                                <span class="error"></span>
                            </label>
                        </section>
                        <section class="col col-6">
                            <label class="input">
                                <i class="icon-append icon-company"></i>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Organization / Company Name" name="companyname">
                            </label>
                        </section>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <section class="col col-6">
                            <label class="input">
                                <i class="icon-append icon-company"></i>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Location" name="location" >
                            </label>
                        </section>
                        <section class="col col-6">
                            <label class="input">
                                <i class="icon-append icon-company"></i>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Job Category  e.g. IT" name="jobcategory">
                            </label>
                        </section>
                        <section class="col col-6">
                            <label class="input">
                                <i class="icon-append icon-company"></i>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Employment Type  e.g. Full Time" name="employmenttype">
                            </label>
                        </section>
                        <section class="col col-6">
                            <label class="input">
                                <i class="icon-append icon-company"></i>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Salary  e.g. 5000$" name="salary">
                            </label>
                        </section>
                        <section class="col col-6">
                            <label class="input">
                                <i class="icon-append icon-company"></i>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Duration  e.g. Permanent" name="duration">
                            </label>
                        </section>
                        <section class="col col-6">
                            <label class="input">
                                <i class="icon-append icon-company"></i> 
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Timing  e.g. 8 AM - 4 PM" name="timing">
                            </label>
                        </section>
                        <section class="col col-6">
                            <label class="input">
                                <i class="icon-append icon-company"></i>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Nationality" name="nationality">
                            </label>
                        </section>
                        <section class="col col-6">
                            <label class="input">
                                <i class="icon-append icon-company"></i>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Number of Vacancy  e.g. 2 Post(s)" name="numberofvacancy">
                            </label>
                        </section>
                        <section class="col col-6">
                            <label class="input">
                                <i class="icon-append icon-company"></i>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Experience  e.g. 3 Years" name="experience">
                            </label>
                        </section>
                        <section class="col col-6">
                            <label class="input">
                                <i class="icon-append icon-company"></i>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Closing Date" id="datepicker" name="closingdate">
                            </label>
                        </section>
                        <section class="col col-6">
                            <label class="input">
                                <i class="icon-append icon-company"></i>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Gender" name="gender">
                            </label>
                        </section>
                        <section class="col col-6">
                            <label class="input">
                                <i class="icon-append icon-company"></i>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Education  e.g. Bachelor" name="education">
                            </label>
                        </section>
                     </div>             
                </fieldset>

                <fieldset>  

                    <section>
                        <label class="textarea">

                            Tell us about your company background
                            <textarea id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80"  name="background" placeholder="Tell us about your company background"></textarea>
                        </label>
                    </section>                  
                    <section>
                        <label class="textarea">

                            Job Summary
                            <textarea id="editor2" rows="10" cols="80"  name="summary" placeholder="Job Summary"></textarea>
                        </label>
                    </section>
                    <section>
                        <label class="textarea">

                            Job Duties and Responsibilities
                            <textarea id="editor3" rows="10" cols="80"  name="duty"  placeholder="Job Duties and Responsibilities"></textarea>
                        </label>
                    </section>
                    <section>
                        <label class="textarea">

                            Qualification Needed
                            <textarea id="editor4" rows="10" cols="80"  name="qualification"  placeholder="Qualification Needed"></textarea>
                        </label>
                    </section>  
                    <section>
                        <label class="textarea">

                            Skills Needed
                            <textarea id="editor5" rows="10" cols="80"   name="skill" placeholder="Skills Needed"></textarea>
                        </label>
                    </section>  
                    <section>
                        <label class="textarea">

                            Submission Guideline
                            <textarea id="editor6" rows="10" cols="80"   name="submission" placeholder="Submission Guideline"></textarea>
                        </label>
                    </section>  
                                        <section>
                        <label class="textarea">

                            Words for making search easy e.g IT | Officer | Manager | ...
                            <textarea id="editor7" rows="10" cols="80"   name="search" placeholder="Words for making search easy e.g IT | Officer | Manager | ... "></textarea>
                        </label>
                    </section>  
                </fieldset>
                <footer>
                    <p>Fill all fields to activate the submit button.</br>
                    Thanks</p><i class="fa fa-check" style="float: right; position: relative; right: 22px; color: white; z-index: 1; padding-top: 23px;"></i><input class="button" type="submit" id="exinput" value="Submit"/>

                   <div style="float: right; padding-right: 10px;"><?php
                   include "../module/back.php";
                   ?></div>
                    </footer>
            </form>

        </div>
```

This is the page where job details are displayed:

```
<div style="width:900px;">
    <div style="float:left; width:200px;"class="ara-form"><header style="font-size:12px; color:#666666; font:Arial, sans-serif; padding:7px;"><?php
   $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM job WHERE id = '".$_GET['id']."' ORDER BY `CreatedTime` DESC");

   $jobdetails = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    echo '<strong>Job Title</strong></br> '.$jobdetails['positiontitle'].'<hr class="job">';
    echo '<strong>Company Name</strong></br> '.$jobdetails['companyname'].'<hr class="job">';
    echo '<strong>Location</strong></br> '.$jobdetails['location'].'<hr class="job">';
    echo '<strong>Closing Date</strong></br> '.$jobdetails['closingdate'].'<hr class="job">';
    echo '<strong>Number of Vacancy</strong></br> '.$jobdetails['numberofvacancy'].'<hr class="job">';
    echo '<strong>Job Category</strong></br> '.$jobdetails['jobcategory'].'<hr class="job">';
    echo '<strong>Duration</strong></br> '.$jobdetails['duration'].'<hr class="job">';
    echo '<strong>Employment Type</strong></br> '.$jobdetails['employmenttype'].'<hr class="job">';
    echo '<strong>Salary</strong></br> '.$jobdetails['salary'].'<hr class="job">';
    echo '<strong>Timing</strong></br> '.$jobdetails['timing'].'<hr class="job">';
    echo '<strong>Nationality</strong></br> '.$jobdetails['nationality'].'<hr class="job">';
    echo '<strong>Gender</strong></br> '.$jobdetails['gender'].'<hr class="job">';
    echo '<strong>Experience</strong></br> '.$jobdetails['experience'].'<hr class="job">';
    echo '<strong>Education</strong></br> '.$jobdetails['education'].'<hr class="job">';
    echo '<strong>Gender</strong></br> '.$jobdetails['gender'].'<hr class="job">';
    echo '<strong>Gender</strong></br> '.$jobdetails['gender'].'<hr class="job">';
?></header>


</div>
    <div style="float:left; width:600px;" class="ara-form">
    <fieldset style="font-size:12px; color:#666666; font:Arial, sans-serif;">


    <div style="width:100px; float:right; padding-left:2px;"><?php
    include "../module/back.php";?>

    <button class="button" style="margin-right: -20px; width: 120px; padding-left: 10px;" value="Go Back"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" style="float: right; position: absolute; right: 6px; color:             white; z-index: 1; padding-top: 31px; margin-top: -20px;"></i><?php
    $query  = "select id from jobviews where job_id=".$job_id."";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    echo "Views  ".mysqli_num_rows($result);?></button>


    <?php
    include "../module/back.php";?>
    <?php
    include "../module/back.php";?>
    </div>



    <?php
    echo '<p><strong id="ara-form">Company Background</strong></br> '.$jobdetails['background'].'</p></br>';
    echo '<p><strong id="ara-form">Job Summary</strong></br> '.$jobdetails['summary'].'</p></br>';
    echo '<p><strong id="ara-form">Job Duties and Responsibilities</strong></br> '.$jobdetails['duty'].'</p></br>';
    echo '<p><strong id="ara-form">Qualification</strong></br> '.$jobdetails['qualification'].'</p></br>';
    echo '<p><strong id="ara-form">Skills</strong></br> '.$jobdetails['skill'].'<hr class="job"></p></br>';
    echo '<p><strong id="ara-form">Submission Guideline</strong></br> '.$jobdetails['submission'].'</p></br>';
    echo '<p><strong id="ara-form">Words to search this job</strong></br> '.$jobdetails['search'].'</p></br>';
    ?>
    </fieldset></div>

    <div style="float:left; width:33.4%; background:#ccc;">three</div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>

</div>
```

This is my MySQL table structure

[image: structure]

Comment: So add an `approved` flag column to the `job` table in your database, and only display records where that flag is true

Comment: Use where on your sql.. where status='approved'

Comment: you should add a flag column in your table named isActive and when you select you will have `"SELECT * FROM job where isActive=1 ORDER BY `CreatedTime` DESC"`

Comment: @MarkBaker I'm not sure he would understand what you're referring to here.

Comment: @MarkBaker, i am new to php and mysql, and i do not know how to write code to approve it from a php page.

Answer (score 0):

Add a field to your table called approved int 1

In your first code block change:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM job ORDER BY `CreatedTime` DESC");
```

to

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM job WHERE approved=1 ORDER BY `CreatedTime` DESC");
```

and also change in your third code block:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM job WHERE id = '".$_GET['id']."' ORDER BY `CreatedTime` DESC");
```

to

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM job WHERE approved=1 AND id = '".$_GET['id']."' ORDER BY `CreatedTime` DESC");
```

You will also need to add some code to approve new submissions to change approved from 0 to 1

Comment: thanks but how i can approve it from admin panel, i mean how should i list all unapproved job in a page and approve the jobs from there.

Answer (score 0):

Add a column in your table that determines whether or not a post has been verified and have it default to false

```
ALTER TABLE `job`  ADD COLUMN `approved` BOOL NOT NULL DEFAULT '0';
```

Then when you validate job post is ok

```
Update job set approved=1 where id='<the_job_post_id>';
```

When you make your query to only see approved

```
SELECT * FROM job where approved=1 ORDER BY `CreatedTime` DESC;
```

Comment: thanks but how i can approve it from admin panel, i mean how should i list all unapproved job in a page and approve the jobs from there.

Comment: SELECT * FROM job where approved=0 ORDER BY `CreatedTime` DESC;
Then just manually set approved to 1 if you want it to be approved.

Comment: thanks but i want to update it from a php page, like a table where jobs which are not approved are listed and in this table in every row their be a approved button which just by clicking that button jobs must to be approved. thanks in advance